# PostgreSQL: Is there a way to clone a row of data in order to populate a table with test data?

Tags: database, postgresql, generate-series

I'm looking for a quick way to populate a table full of constraints and complications to essentially clone two rows over a thousand times, in order to have a base of 1000+ rows to test on.

I understand the basic structure should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO footbl( 
   foo1, foo2, foo3
)
SELECT foo,
       foo1,
       foo3
FROM footbl WHERE id=1;
```

How do I take this statement and have it do this a thousand times?

EDIT:

While attempting the generate_series solution -

```
INSERT INTO footbl(foo1, foo2, foo3)
    SELECT foo, foo1, foo3
    FROM footbl CROSS JOIN
         generate_series(1, 1000)
    WHERE pk = 1;
```

I get the following errors.

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk" 
DETAIL: Key (pk)=(1) already exists.
```

I attempted using the next value of pk but then it inserts nothing.

```
INSERT 0 0
```

Removing pk from the listed columns to allow it to auto-generate entirely gives the error that the null value in column "pk" violates not-null constraint. Viewing the table definition for "pk":

```
pk | bigint | not null | plain
```

And some further clarification provided in the comments also, this database is a skeleton database pulled from a client. I brought in *just* the schema and global definitions, and 2 rows of data. For complicated reasons, I'm not able to go back in to their database to export 1000 rows of data, so I'm looking to specifically clone 1 of the 2 existing rows, 1000 times. This also means that I very preferably do not want to modify the existing constraints, modifiers, anything, and leave the schema exactly as it is, in order to have accurate testing against this cloned database.

SECOND EDIT:

Due to lack of time, I went ahead and modified the schema as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN pk SET DEFAULT nextval('temp_id_seq');
```

This solved my issue of the conflicting PK and allowed the rows to be generated. However, if anyone has any ideas how to achieve the same thing *without* modifying the schema, please comment below and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: why not use python and inject random data to the database table, use sth like psycopg2

Comment: How is the PK value generated? Do you have a sequence for that? If not, why?

Comment: No, there's no sequence. If you read the post, you'll see that this is *not* my schema; it's classified as bigint. This is a client schema, that's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`:

```
INSERT INTO footbl(foo1, foo2, foo3)
    SELECT foo, foo1, foo3
    FROM footbl CROSS JOIN
         generate_series(1, 1000)
    WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: that's a nice way to duplicate rows

Comment: Hmm, I was considering that, but how would you handle each column being a different type of data? (e.g. bigint, timestamp, timestamptz, text, etc)

Comment: @IAspireToBeGladOS: This works for *any* mix of data types as is.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize! OK. Any ideas how to fix:

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk"
DETAIL: Key (pk)=(1) already exists.

? I attempted using the next value of pk but then it inserts nothing.

Comment: Removing pk from the listed columns entirely gives the error that the null value in column "pk" violates not-null constraint.

Comment: @IAspireToBeGladOS . . . This answers the question that you asked.  It multiplies each row one thousand times.  If you have a primary key, I would suggest that you make it `serial` and let the database generate it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using this as a skeleton version of a client database. I need to generate enough data to test scripts against, but not change any of their data types or constraints to ensure everything runs as expected. Worst case I can change that data type, but I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @IAspireToBeGladOS . . . You can use the value provided by `generate_series()` as a column value.

Comment: If you read the comments I provided earlier, you can see the exact errors I get for trying three different scenarios. It doesn't seem to like the generate_series value, either that or it doesn't like selecting the id = 1 value.

Comment: @IAspireToBeGladOS: how is the PK column of that table defined? ([EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46576265/edit) your question and add the complete `create table` statement. Do **NOT** post code in comments)

Comment: Updated my original post.